# box-shadow not working properly in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

I have the following code:

```
a.menu_item{
    box-shadow: .8px .8px 0px 0px #ffffff,3px 3px 0px 0px #676568;
    -webkit-box-shadow: .8px .8px 0px 0px #ffffff,3px 3px 0px 0px #676568;
    -moz-box-shadow: .8px .8px 0px 0px #ffffff,3px 3px 0px 0px #676568;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Working propely in IE9, 10 and Firefox- displays a white border on the bottom and the right and another one like a shadow outside the first border. The problem is that in chrome, the white border is not displayed. Any idea?

Comment: You're drawing a shadow. Why do you expect a white border?

Comment: What is .8px ? 4/5ths of a pixel? Is this allowed nowadays or is it an oversight?

Comment: @moopet client insisted it is 0.8px, I have no idea why. I also taught it's quite stupid.

Comment: Well in order to exclude such things, what happens if you replace .8px with 1px, for example? Is it then at least consistent between browsers?

Comment: 0.8 is rounded and rendered as 1px border, in mozilla it's treated as zero. (it's just a guess)

Comment: Yeah, seems like chrome treats it as 0. Thanks

Comment: you don't need vendor prefix for box-shadow any more.